# Adding reference to a project outside of solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a project outside of my solution directory. That project is in "C:\myproject\" directory. Now I want to add a reference to it from my project which is in default project directory for VS projects.

I opened the project properties in VS2013 and to reference path I added that directory ("C:\myproject\") and when I want to add areference to it, window (in which I add references) displays nothing (there's not a single project listed to which I can add reference).

What happened to plain old way to find path and click on .vcproj file? How can I solve my problem?