# Add reference to nuget package outside of solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Similar question for c++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919429/adding-reference-to-a-project-outside-of-solution)

I've installed a package with `nuget install` and am using the `csc.exe` executable to compile c# files (and then execute via command line with `$ ./test.exe`) outside of a solution/asp.net project. My structure looks like this so far.

```
/lib
  test.cs
  test.exe
/packages
  /RazorMachine.2.6.1
```

Inside `test.cs` I need access to the `RazorMachine` class but am not sure how of the `using` syntax for accessing a local package? According to MSDN docs I can:

> create an alias for a namespace or a type. This is called a using alias directive.

```
// need to reference directory structure?
using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;
// definitely wrong
using RazorMachine = ./../packages/RazorMachine.2.6.1
```

I'm not sure what the correct terminology is to search for in the docs. I feel like I need some xml configuration to tell the program where to find the packages.

Comment: `csc.exe` isn't executing C# files. It's compiling them to an executable (exe) which you would then execute.

Comment: yes i've got that down, not sure how to actually write the correct c# file though

Comment: sprry my terminology wasn't correct, meant compile, not execute.

Comment: Well you stated it wrong in your question, which is why I pointed it out. Anyways, you don't modify the C# file. You just need to tell the compiler where the assemblies are you're referencing. I suggest you look up the documentation for `csc.exe` and see how you reference libraries. There's an example of this referencing in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722832/csc-exe-reference-external-dll-file).